# Dynamic HTML Table with Fixed Header and Fixed First column

Tags: css, header, fixed, datatables

I am creating a html table dynamically and filling in its contents. After that I add the complete HTML to a div already on my aspx page. I want to fix the header of the dynamic table and its first column. So far I have tried FixedHeader,datatable and fixedcolumn plugins but nothing seems to be working.

Kindly help if I need some css or something else I am missing.

Comment: Can you share fiddle?

Answer (score 5):

Hi if are ready to built one of such i can help you with that.

check out the following fiddle for demo if it helps.[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/52/)

I have used jquery's `.scroll()` check if u can

Please tell me if it helps.

Comment: is there a way to add resizing feature for this table structure?

Comment: How can i make the table responsive?