# Laggy element position update on mobile scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I'm trying to make a sticky header + first column table. Works fine on desktop browsers.

However, when I scroll the table's x-axis on a mobile device, the position update is dragging i.e. not fast enough.

I've read various SO-threads that suggest [iScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll). I'm not really sure how to use it appropriately in this case. Should intercept the `tbody` scroll event, perevent the default behaviour and update the position based on iScroll's event values? Please point me in the right direction here :)

```
$(function() {
  var $tbody = $('tbody');

  $tbody.on('scroll', function(e) { 
    var left = $tbody.scrollLeft();
    $('thead').css('left', -left); 
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1), thead th:nth-child(1)').css('left', left);
  });

  var iScroll = new IScroll($tbody[0], { probeType: 3 });
  iScroll.on('scroll', function(){
    console.log('not fired?');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97r799gr/

To reproduce the problem, it's probably easiest for you to visit https://jsfiddle.net/97r799gr/show on your mobile. I'm using an SGS7 edge so I think this will be reproducible on pretty much any mobile device.

Comment: I will go on a guessig spree and say that the use of selectors is extremely inneficient. Try storing the results into variables.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Could have been the case, but it's not :)

Comment: You could try replacing every single `td:nth-child(1)` with `td:first-child`. Then, add `var $thead= $('thead');` under the `var $tbody`. `$('thead').css('left', -left);` can be replaced with `$thead.css('left', -left);`. Then, replace `$('tbody td:nth-child(1), thead th:nth-child(1)')` with `$tbody.find('td:first-child').css('left', left);
$thead.find('th:first-child').css('left', left);`. This should work and speed up things a bit. You could go a bit further and store those results into a var

Comment: Actually, the simplest answer is: Just use [datatables](https://datatables.net/)! Here's what you want to implement: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html It is one heavy plugin, but does anything you need with the table.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks, but the problem is that the datatables plugin is rather laggy on a mobile device too...

Comment: Then there's something else burning CPU time

Comment: I just tested this on my mac laptop in safari 10.0.2 and it is super laggy as well - so not just mobile!

Comment: A different approach might be to make the table scrollable (instead of the page) and set the names set as position absolute (using js to calculate there position on page load / resize).

Comment: Check here, this may help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402295/html-table-with-horizontal-scrolling-first-column-fixed You may also be interested in https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

Comment: I have done something similar, but I'm using Zurb's Foundation. Have a look at their responsive table plugin here: http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables

Comment: @WimMertens Still only one axis though? I need both a sticky header and first column

Comment: @Johan, yes you're right. Found this post, might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449339/dynamic-html-table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-first-column check the fiddle in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/52/

Comment: @WimMertens Thanks, but it's the same solution more or less :/ The difference beeing using js for the y axis instead of x...

Comment: @WimMertens a little laggy on anroid. But it works!

Answer (score 2):

`IScroll` uses a wrapper with fixed dimensions with one scrollable content in it. Therefore we can't use `tbody` as a wrapper. We should wrap the whole table and hold desired elements with CSS when scrolling.

I've created a fiddle with `iscroll-probe.js` code in it (`iscroll.js` hasn't got a `scroll` event). Bad news is that it works only on my iPhone. Scrolling is suddenly stops when scrolling it on my android5.1 device.

```
// main code
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#pos').text('initialize iscroll');
  try{
    var iScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { 
      interactiveScrollbars: true, 
      scrollbars: true, 
      scrollX: true, 
      probeType: 3, 
      useTransition:false, 
      bounce:false
    });
  } catch(e) {
    $('#error').text('Error ' + e.name + ":" + e.message + "\n" + e.stack);
  }

  $('#pos').text('initialized');

  iScroll.on('scroll', function(){
    var pos = $('#scroller').position();
    $('#pos').text('pos.left=' + pos.left + ' pos.top=' + pos.top);

    // code to hold first row and first column
    $('#scroller th:nth-child(1)').css({top: (-pos.top), left: (-pos.left), position:'relative'});
    $('#scroller th:nth-child(n+1)').css({top: (-pos.top), position:'relative'});

    $('#scroller td:nth-child(1)').css({left: (-pos.left), position:'relative'});
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qv1kjac/11/

Comment: Awesome, this looks promising! Any ideas about the android problem though? I'm experiencing it too

Comment: I can't improve the answer any more. It is a known issue. https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/91 and https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/751 can possibly help you.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: @Johan This does not work on desktop (at least not macOS Sierra, Chrome 55). You're ok with an iPhone-only solution?

Comment: @tony19 Yeah, my main concern was the iPad actually. Thanks for asking :) Also, it works fine on latest Chrome on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make it work with pure CSS, so I decided to remove iScroll and rewrite the javascript in vanilla js.  It works fine on my iphone now.  I don't have an android to test with.

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66a1b2rw/

Everything is the same as your original fiddle except the js:

### updated js

```
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
var thead = document.querySelector('thead');
var firstCol = document.querySelectorAll('tbody td:nth-child(1), thead th:nth-child(1)');
console.log(firstCol);
tbody.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var left = tbody.scrollLeft;
  thead.style.left = '-' + left + 'px';
  firstCol.forEach(function(x) {x.style.left = left + 'px'})
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid this didn't help much for me though. I think you need to resort to a third party framework like iScroll to intercept the native scrolling event